# Remoting using a specific object

Tags: c#, xna, remoting

I've been playing with XNA and want to try and make a game work over LAN but it turns out that to do this I need to use something called remoting. Anyway I managed to get this to work

```
    public class TestObject : MarshalByRefObject
{
    int testInt;

    public Level()
    {
        this.testInt = 5.Zero;
    }


    public int GetNumber()
    {
        return testInt;
    }
}
```

and my server
            channel = new TcpChannel(4444);
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);

```
        Type type = Type.GetType("Domain.Level,Domain");

        RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(type,
            "FirstRemote",
            WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
```

and client

```
      this.chanel = new TcpChannel();
      ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chanel, false);
      this.testObject = (TestObject)Activator.GetObject(typeof(TestObject),
         "tcp://localhost:4444/FirstRemote");
```

so that works but the problem is that the server has no way to access the object and I cant make a constructor that takes arguments so there is no way to initialize any data on the test object. How do I make an object, and then make it use that instead of making a new object?

Comment: Why do you need to use Remoting? It has pretty much been replaced with WCF.

Comment: WCF? Will that do what I want? I dont exactly know what it is or have ever heard of it.

Comment: In general, WCF will do what you want. I'm not an XNA expert, so it's possible that XNA doesn't support WCF. You'll have to check. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/wcf/info.

Comment: Apparently WCF only supports HTTP and HTTP is meant to be slower than ICP. It looks like WCF is used more for web based stuff and I only need LAN stuff.

Comment: WCF supports many protocols, including TCP. It is used for all networking scenarios. It is possible that WCF on XNA only supports HTTP and HTTPS. If you don't need the absolute highest speed, then that's not an issue. If your application needs the highest possible speed, then with WCF you can create your own transport, using TCP/IP, then use it on client and service sides. This gives you the optimal speed while giving you only one piece of code to support (the transport). Your higher layers will be WCF, which is likely to last at least another decade.

Comment: Forget you ever heard of remoting. WCF is a much better choice.

Comment: Im pretty sure you guys would know better than me so Ill try to make this WCF thing work. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you'll probably find that realtime network communication in games is more complex than the current direction you're taking. Most games use persistent socket connections to pass information back and forth between clients and other methods are generally too slow for *realtime* networking.

I recommend looking into the Lidgren networking library. Lidgren abstracts network communication and makes it much easier to serialize data into very small and fast packets that can be transferred via several reliability modes across UDP and TCP. You can find the Lidgren project here:
http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/

As a side note, it was very valuable for me to read how the Unreal Engine does networking here:
http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/NetworkingOverview.html

And I wrote a blog that demonstrates some specific details about implementing a client/server pattern:
http://syndicatex.com/flatredball/flatredball-and-lidgren-multiplayer-networking/